# Use a different PHP Upstream based on arguments in the URL - NGinx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, wordpress

I run Nginx and PHP-FPM. Nginx runs under www-data and PHP-FPM runs as a separate user for each website. I use Nginx FASTCGI Caching and use the Nginx Helper plugin for WordPress. Unfortunately due to the difference in user we can't use the "Purge All" function in the plugin as the php user doesn't have access to the cache.

Changing permissions isn't an option due to security.

What I want to do is use a different PHP-FPM Pool if the below argument exists in the URL.

```
nginx_helper_urls=all
```

My current NGinx Config is below:

```
    upstream examplebackend {
        server unix:/var/run/php-fcgi-example.sock;
}

upstream cachedeletebackend {
        server unix:/var/run/php-fcgi-cachedelete.sock;
}

server {
        listen 80 default;
        server_name www.example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    access_log   /home/examplecom/logs/example.com.access.log;
    error_log    /home/examplecom/logs/example.com.error.log;

    root /home/examplecom/public_html;
    index index.php;

    set $skip_cache 0;

    # POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }   
    if ($query_string != "") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }   

    # Don't cache uris containing the following segments
    if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }   

    # Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }    

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404; 
        include fastcgi_params;
    if ( $args ~ nginx_helper_urls=all ) { fastcgi_pass cachedeletebackend; }
        fastcgi_pass examplebackend;

        fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
            fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;

        fastcgi_cache WORDPRESS;
        fastcgi_cache_valid  60m;
    }

    location ~ /purge(/.*) {
        fastcgi_cache_purge WORDPRESS "$scheme$request_method$host$1";
    }   

    location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
    }

    location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location ~ /\. { deny  all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }
}
```

Not sure where I am going wrong or if it is even possible. Thanks

Comment: What happens when you try to call this URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This likely happens because [If is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

In nginx, most of the `if` statements should be implemented with `map` feature instead.

In your case, first define the `map` in `http` level:

```
map $arg_nginx_helper_urls $backend {
    all cachedeletebackend;
    default examplebackend;
}
```

Then, in PHP `location` block use:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404; 
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass $backend;

    fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
    fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;

    fastcgi_cache WORDPRESS;
    fastcgi_cache_valid  60m;
}
```

The map will assign a value to `$backend` variable depending on query argument `nginx_helper_urls` value. By default, `examplebackend` is used. If the argument value is `all`, then `cachedeletebackend` is assigned to the variable.

Comment: This works perfectly on my current server which does only have one website. If I am to use this on my server with multiple sites with multiple different backends per site plus the cachedeletebackend. Where abouts in the config should I place the code to ensure its in the correct location. Would above the server section in each virtualconf file be adaquate?

Comment: You would configure `upstream examplebackend` and `upstream cachedeletebackend` accordingly for each of your virtual hosts. In Debian systems, you can put the `map` section into `conf.d/cachemap.conf` for example and it will work from there.